# Reputation Glitch

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I am having an issues with my reputation. Namely, I get upvoted/have an answer accepted but don't receive any reputation. Examples of this are:

1. [$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$ is not a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466885/mathbbqx-y-y2-x3-is-not-a-ufd/466900#466900)
2. [If $K$ is finite, then every subset of $\mathbb A^n(K)$ is algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466873/if-k-is-finite-then-every-subset-of-mathbb-ank-is-algebraic/466882#466882)

Often times the glitch fixes itself by later, retroactively assigning me the reputation.

I just wanted to point this out, in case it was indicative of some more serious problem!

Comment: Did you used to hang around mathhelpforum a couple of years ago?...

Comment: @user1729 Indeed, as Drexel28.

Comment: Thought so. I remember your blog, which you link to in your profile. I was Swlabr back then.

Comment: @user1729 Ah, very cool! It looks like you've taken up geometric group theory interests since then, perhaps.

Comment: I was doing that then, but there wasn't much scope for it there. Plus, I've got better at it now!

Comment: @user1729 Very cool. Are you at a US school? I believe I recall you being British.

Comment: I am still in the UK, but currently looking for jobs (which could mean anywhere!) What is your subject? I would suspect groups, but I can't quite tell...

Comment: @user1729 I don't know yet, I'm just about to enter grad school. Arithmetic geometry interests me greatly, so probably something in that field. Or, perhaps some other form of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Ian Agol is as Berkeley - you should get in with him! He is one of the "men of the moment" in geometric group theory. He used work of Dani Wise to prove the virtually Haken conjecture, which "reproves" geometrisation (not really - the result, as a stand-alone entity, *implies* geometrisation, but they used geometrisation in their proof...). Anyway, massive result.

Comment: @user1729 Haha, I am well-aware of the magnitude of Ian Agol. I will definitely try and learn something from him at least.

Comment: Have you two never heard of email?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Are those that form of electronic carrier pigeon>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No bug - you have just hit the daily reputation limit (congratulations!).

You have received 217 rep today. The maximum you can gain from votes is 200. The extra 17 comes from a +15 from someone accepting an answer of yours and a +2 from you accepting an answer. These don't count towards the limit. See the [reputation help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for more details. See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/capped-reputation) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40714/how-do-i-know-if-ive-reached-my-daily-rep-cap) for related discussions.

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of this limit! I will accept your answer as soon as I can--apparently I have to wait 5 minutes--who knew!

Comment: I was confused by the same thing the first time it happened to me. The reputation page ought to have an explanation when this happens, instead of leaving the reputation amount blank or filling in what appears to be a wrong value.